# Can't change the name of the legend

Tags: r

I have a dataset like these

| Region | Greenspace | Bluespace |
| --- | --- | --- |
| North | 30 | 5 |
| South | 50 | 10 |
| West | 15 | 2 |
| East | 10 | 1 |

```
data <- data.frame (  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Region = c("North", "South", "West", "East"),
  Greenspace = c(30,50,15,10),
  Bluespace = c(5,10,2,1)
)
```

I want to create a histogram showing the regions in the x-axis and percentage in the yaxis. I used that code

```
data %>% pivot_longer(cols = Greenspace:Bluespace) %>% ggplot(aes(x = Region, y = value, fill = name)) + geom_col(position = 'dodge') + ggtitle("Contrast between 4 different region areas for Greenspace and Bluespace") + xlab("Region") + ylab("percentage")+ scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "dark green"))
```

Now the problem is instead of name i want space in the legend. I change fill into name but got error message could not find space.

But the problem is i don't want name, I want space

Has anyone an idea how to fix it. I appreciate every help :)

[image]

Comment: `scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "dark green"), "space")`?

Comment: Yes, apologise, didn't see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what `labs` is for. You can assign names to the different aesthetics, which will then be shown as the title of this aesthetic:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = Greenspace:Bluespace) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Region, y = value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
  ggtitle("Contrast between 4 different region areas for Greenspace and Bluespace") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Bluespace = "blue", 
                               Greenspace = "dark green")) +
  labs(x = "Region", y = "percentage", fill = "space")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I think this becomes clear when looking at the x and y aesthetic, which you labeled using the special functions `xlab` and `ylab`. If you put this within `labs` the axis titles change. As a side note, you can remove the title of an aesthetic by setting, for example, `labs(fill = NULL)` or `labs(fill = "")`.